# Creating a .py file rather than .txt file using open(file_name, "w+")

Tags: python, file-io

I have a text file that I created using

```
 open(new_file_name_string,"w+")
```

I want to know if/how I can use the open function (or any other python function) to create a python (.py) file instead of a text (.txt) file. For instance, can I use a different argument than "w+" to make open generate a python file?

If there is nothing like this available, is there a python function that can convert my .txt file into a .py file?

Comment: That's just an extension. If `new_file_name_string.endswith('.py')`, it's a Python file.

Comment: Nothing makes a .py file distinct from a .txt file. Those are just standardized extensions. It's the content of the files that allows a text editor or the Python interpreter to understand them correctly.

Comment: What's stopping you? When you tried, what specific error or problem did you encounter? (Mind you, code generation is an experts-only practice with a bunch of serious security caveats -- folks with enough expertise to know when it can be done safely also have enough expertise to use Pickle/JSON/msgpack/AST-based bytecode generation/otherwise something else instead -- but there's nothing that prevents you from doing it -- only things that prevent you from being able to do it *safely*, *securely*, or *advisedly*).

Comment: I understand that I can manually change the extension name, however I want my program to do this in the script as described above. I cannot manually change the files or else my code breaks because this python file that is generated is only an intermediate step. Does anyone know how to change the extension for the .txt file that I generated in my code to .py through python or how to generate a .py rather than .txt file in the first place?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, what is stopping me is that I cannot get a .py file to be generated. I don't know which argument to use in the following: open(new_file_name_string,"w+"). Should I use ".py" instead of "w+"? Or is this even possible with the "open" function. I am not concerned about security because this is just for a school project and will make my life a lot easier

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried adding .py to my new_file_name_string argument and I still don't get a python file as an output

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just got it to work thanks to your advice. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

if you mean that you want to change the extension, just change the filename. If your previous filename is just `filename` or `filename.txt` just change it to `filename.py`

Comment: I understand that I can manually change the extension name, however I want my program to do this in the script as described above. I cannot manually change the files or else my code breaks because this python file that is generated is only an intermediate step. Do you know how to change the extension for the .txt file that I generated in my code to .py through python or how to generate a .py rather than .txt file in the first place?

Comment: yeah, I meant the filename in your code. like filename = 'filename' + '.py'. For example open('new_file.py','w+'). Or do you mean something else?